# iOS Simulatore in Sierra - Studio Midi does not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, macos-sierra, coremidi

I am encountering very bad problem using Sierra + xcode 8 + iOS Simulator:
I develop midi application, but now , when I start the iOS Simulator I get no midi-port available, I mean: Usualle using Studio Midi is possible to see the virtual iOS device, plus you can see se the session, typically named Session 1.
being this is possible to re-route the MidiNetwork ( midi_driver ) to a physical port, but now, using Sierra the iOS Simulatore is not visible no longer, and I do not know ( and where to find ) a solution. Very bad situation because it stopped the developing and code-production. Any Good idea to solve this????

Comment: Exact duplicate of [iOS Simulator in Sierra - Studio Midi does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856039/ios-simulator-in-sierra-studio-midi-does-not-work) from the same poster

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
Check to make sure you don't have duplicates of the CoreMIDI.Framework in your project. *If present remove the reference to the duplicate CoreMIDI.Framework (highlight, tap delete)

Product > Clean

Run the iOS Simulator
```

Comment: the main problem is that iOS simulator is not visible at port 5004