# iOS Simulator in Sierra - Studio Midi does not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, macos-sierra, coremidi

I am encountering very bad problem using Sierra + xcode 8 + iOS Simulator: I develop midi application, but now , when I start the iOS Simulator I get no midi-port available, I mean: Usualle using Studio Midi is possible to see the virtual iOS device, plus you can see se the session, typically named Session 1. being this is possible to re-route the MidiNetwork ( midi_driver ) to a physical port, but now, using Sierra the iOS Simulatore is not visible no longer, and I do not know ( and where to find ) a solution. Very bad situation because it stopped the developing and code-production. Any Good idea to solve this????

[image]

[image]

then I tried: 
1 - Removing duplicates of the CoreMIDI.Framework in project

2 - Product > Clean

3 - Run the iOS Simulator

but nothing still works

Comment: Please file a bug at https://bugreporter.apple.com and include this information

Comment: I did it since long time, but never get any answer yet

Comment: Can you give me the bug #?

Comment: the Bug No. is : 29365916

Comment: the problem is: iOS Simulator or Sierra do not open port 5004